# Next.js 13.5 error on production - json.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column * of the json data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, vercel, react-query

I have an app developed in Next.js 13.5 (not app router) that obtains firestore data by making a call to a route api using useInfiniteQuery from tankstack/reack query v4 for pagination.

In development it works fine but in production (vercel) it does the initial loading of 10 documents but then freezes and returns the following error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: end of data after property value in object at line 1 column 163648 of the JSON data.

Fetch function:

```
const fetchData = async ({ pageParam = 0, queryKey }) => {
  const [_key, filtroPatente] = queryKey
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      `/api/data?startAfter=${
        pageParam || 0
      }&filtroPatente=${filtroPatente}&col=despacho`
    )
    let data = await res.json()

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${res.status}`)
    }
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    throw error
  }
}
```

useInfiniteQuery:

```
const {
    data,
    error,
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
    isFetchingNextPage,
    refetch,
    remove,
  } = useInfiniteQuery(['despacho', patente], fetchData, {
    optional: true,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    keepPreviousData: true,
    onSuccess: () => setIsTableLoading(false),
    onError: () => setIsTableLoading(false),
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => lastPage.hasNextPage && lastPage.lastDocId,
    select: (data) => {
      data.pageParams = data.pageParams.filter((param) => param !== undefined)
      return data
    },
  })
```

useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        if (entries[0].isIntersecting && hasNextPage && !isFetchingNextPage) {
          fetchNextPage()
        }
      },
      { threshold: 1 }
    )

    if (loader.current) {
      observer.observe(loader.current)
    }

    return () => {
      observer.disconnect()
    }
  }, [hasNextPage, isFetchingNextPage])
```

Api route:

```
import { db } from '@/lib/firebase-admin' //firebase-admin

export default async (req, res) => {
  const limit = 10
  try {
    const { startAfter = '', filtroPatente = '', col } = req.query
    let ref = db.collection(col).orderBy('fecha', 'desc').limit(limit)

    if (filtroPatente) {
      ref = ref.where('vehiculo.patente', '==', filtroPatente)
    }

    if (startAfter) {
      const startAfterDoc = await db.collection(col).doc(startAfter).get()
      if (startAfterDoc.exists) {
        ref = ref.startAfter(startAfterDoc)
      }
    }

    const snapshot = await ref.limit(limit).get()
    const data = []
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      data.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
    })

    const hasNextPage = data.length === limit
    const lastDocId = data[data.length - 1]?.id || ''
    // console.log(data)
    res.status(200).json({ data, lastDocId, hasNextPage })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).json({
      error: 'An error occurred while fetching data!',
      message: error.message,
    })
  }
}
```

Adititional info:

- Node v18 on both environments.
- Next.js v13.5.4
- firebase v10.4.0
- firebase-admin 11.11.0
- tanstack/react-query v4.35.7

Any idea what could be causing the problem?

I have tried a lot of changes but have not been successful. It catches my attention that it works locally and not in production.

Comment: Ignore the frontend for now and make a request to the production backend with some other tool, e.g. curl. Inspect the response with some json prettifier tool. Is the response complete? In that case it's a frontend issue, otherwise it's a backend issue.